# Difficulty following textbook equation

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, ising-model

I am currently reading through Yeomans Statistical Mechanics of Phase Transitions and on page 53 they show equation 4.15 as follows

$$
\langle s\rangle_0 = \langle s\rangle_0/(t+1)) - \langle s\rangle_0^3/3(1+t)^3) + O(\langle s\rangle_0^5/(t+1)^5)
$$

this is just an expansion of

$$
\langle s\rangle_0 = \tanh(\langle s\rangle_0/1+t)
$$

around small $s$ and $t$. Equation 4.16 however says

$$
\langle s\rangle_0 = \langle s\rangle_0(t-1) - \dfrac{\langle s\rangle_0^3}{3} + O(\langle s\rangle_0t^2,\langle s\rangle_0t^3,\langle s\rangle_0^5)
$$

I do not understand how you get from 4.15 to 4.16 as much of the dirty work is obscured in the big O notation any help or pointers is much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I've just cracked it, minutes after posting, classic.

The solution is that

$$
\langle s\rangle_0 = \langle s\rangle_0/(t+1) - \langle s\rangle_0^3/3(t+1)^3) + O(\langle s\rangle_0^5/(1+t)^5)
$$

is the expansion of the transcendental equation around small *m*, and then taking that equation and expanding around small *t* we get...

$$
\langle s\rangle_0 = \langle s\rangle_0(t-1) - \langle s\rangle_0^3/3 + O(\langle s\rangle_0t^2,\langle s\rangle_0t^3,\langle s\rangle_0^5)
$$